# Archive build fails with specific Swift Package Manager library

Tags: xcode11, build-error, swift-package-manager

I am having "archive build" issues when using the following library:
https://github.com/kieranb662/Interact

- I have integrated the library via Swift Package Manager.
- I am able to build and run on both the simulator and on my device.
- When I attempt to perform an archive build to make an .ipa build I get attached screen shot errors.

At first I suspected that SPM wasn’t setup correctly so I forked the code here:
https://github.com/xdeleon/Interact

I then added the following to the Packages.swift file:
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v13), .tvOS(.v13), .watchOS(.v6)
    ],

The above changes in my forked code did not resolve the issue.

It’s confusing that this will build and install on my device but Xcode fails to produce archive build. The app I am working on uses several other public libraries via SPM and an internal library we build available via SPM as well and the app builds without issues.

Stripped Down Steps to Reproduce:
- Create new project with Xcode 11.3
- Integrate the SPM library with either one of two URL’s:
         https://github.com/kieranb662/Interact (original)
         https://github.com/xdeleon/Interact (my fork)
- Attempt to make archive build
- Archive build fails
[image: Error Message]

Comment: When using SwiftPM import statements are much more strict. You have to import all of your dependencies unless the have an `@_exported` applied to one of the imports in your module. In this case you need to use `import Combine` in all the files complaining about not knowing what `@Published` is.

Comment: Thx. Ended up using `import Combine`. I did not use `@_exported` as there is discussion about this not being officially part of Swift yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558995/what-is-the-exported-attribute-in-swift